# Get image with Axios request and send it to express js response

Tags: javascript, image, rest, express, axios

I am using express js endpoint that makes a `GET` request with `axios` which outputs an image. Then send this image to response output of endpoint:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const token = 'Bearer key-auth'
app.get('/test', async (req, res, next) => {

    const arrayBuffer = await axios.get('example/url/image',
            { headers: { Authorization: token, responseType: "arraybuffer" }})
     res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
        'Content-Length': arrayBuffer.data.length
      })
    res.send(arrayBuffer.data)

})
```

This works.. the API returns status 200. However the image returned is broken and nothing is previewd in browser except for the broken image icon:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd start by using the Network tab of the browser to see what the response body from the API is. Also use `wget` or `curl` to save the `/test` URL response body and then a tool like `file` (standard UNIX tool) or `identify` (part of ImageMagick) to see what it says about the data in the response (i.e. to see if it is a PNG or something else))

Comment: The output header has `Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf-8`. The source output contains `�PNG .....`

Comment: Has it got resolved?

Comment: @PakornK I had the same problem this morning. And I solved it. I'm posting an answer for anyone who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since this morning, and finally solved it. It depends on the client you use to make the request. Latest versions of axios usually convert some response type automatically, so that you end up using and sending the converted format instead of the original format.

The key is to tell axios that the `responseType` is Array Buffer like you did. BUT, `responseType` is not a standard HTTP Header. It is a custom parameter of axios, so you have to put it outside of headers. In this case it would be:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const token = 'Bearer key-auth'
app.get('/test', async (req, res, next) => {

    const arrayBuffer = await axios.get('example/url/image', {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: { Authorization: token }
    })
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
        'Content-Length': arrayBuffer.data.length
      })
    res.send(arrayBuffer.data)
})
```